# Javascript spilt function does not recognise one of the tabs in my string

Tags: javascript, split, tabs

I have a string with tab-separated data copied from Excel. The javascript split does not recognise the 2nd tab in the string. I have pasted the string into notepad++ to see the tabs and they are all there. Exploding the string in PHP works fine. The test code is:

```
    function testTab(str) {
        var strSplit = str.split('\t');
        for (i=0; i < strSplit.length; i++){
            console.log('strSplit['+i+'] = '+strSplit[i]);
        }
    }
```

The console output (where the tab between 1st and 2nd item is not recognised):

```
strSplit[0] = 0.02194 0.028940568
strSplit[1] = 0.05227
strSplit[2] = 0.040229885
strSplit[3] = 0.04650
strSplit[4] = 0.035630689
strSplit[5] = 0.07055
strSplit[6] = 0.015557256
strSplit[7] = 0.01960
strSplit[8] = 0.03527
strSplit[9] = 0.05276
strSplit[10] = 0.05669
strSplit[11] = 0.05680
strSplit[12] = 0.04464
strSplit[13] = 1
```

Unsure if the string copies correctly with all tabs, but here it is:

```js
const str = `0.02194 0.028940568 0.05227 0.040229885 0.04650 0.035630689 0.07055 0.015557256 0.01960 0.03527 0.05276 0.05669 0.05680 0.04464 1`;

function testTab(str) {
  var strSplit = str.split('\t');
  for (i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++) {
    console.log('strSplit[' + i + '] = ' + strSplit[i]);
  }
}

testTab(str)
```

Comment: I don't know how to get actual tab characters posted here, so it's really impossible to tell what's going on. The JavaScript `.split()` function is not broken however.

Comment: You can do something like `console.log(str.charCodeAt(7))` and verify that the value is the tab character (09).

Comment: I made a snippet. Looks like it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions, it inspired me to review all options.

I changed the delimiters in the regex so that the split now reads:

```
var strSplit = str.split(/\t/);
```

For some reason it now works.